# Right div overlapping left fixed div

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: The overlap]I have a class row and inside I have one left div which occupies 30% and one right div, which occupies 70%. I want to make the left div fixed such that when I scrolls it keeps its position. However, when I use position fixed on left div, the right div comes on it. How do I solve this issue?

Here is my code snippet:

```
div .profile_left{
border: 1px solid black;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
padding: 0px;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
-ms-word-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
text-align: center;
 }

<div class="container">
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="profile_left col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 
         col-xs-12" style="width: 30%;">
           <div style="background-color: #01226c; text- 
            align:center; padding:20px;">
           <h3 style="color: white;"><strong>PROFILE</strong> 
            </h3>
            </div>
         </div>


<div class="profile_right col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs- 
12" style="width: 70%;">
  <div style="background-color:white; 
   overflow:hidden; padding:20px; border-radius:5px; margin- 
    bottom:10px;" class="contact_info">
    <h4 style="float: left; margin-bottom: 10px; 
    <strong>Contact Information</strong></h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We can't see the issue. Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to examine.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` it will lose it's relative position. So one way to do this is to add a `margin-left: 30%` to the right div.

Or make elements inside the left div `position: fixed` with the left div container or parent element having `position: relative`.

I hope it makes sense to you.

Or use `position: sticky` with `top` property like below for example:

Since `sticky` conserves the element position, so this would be a better approach than `position: fixed`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  margin: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="left">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    some content
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it is still overlapping but less. The right part of the fixed div is overlapping with the left part of the right div to some amount

Comment: Please add an image or some sort of a view to see how the overlapping is happening

Comment: @Alpha Also why you're adding width properties to bootstrap width classes?

Comment: added. I added because it was not rendering well

Comment: @Alpha Try to add sticky instead of fixed. I'll provide an example in a minute

Comment: I dnt want to fix the size of my divs. Their heights should adjust to the contents also

Comment: Using border-box model might help

Answer (score 0):

Keep the navigation (left box) fixed & page (content box) as usual with left margin equal to navigation.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SKJoy2001/7z32egqn/26/

HTML

```
<div class="Page">
  <div class="Navigation">
    <h2>Sticky navigation</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Content">
    <h1>Regular content</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
:root{
  --PageWidth: 640px;
  --NavigationWidth: 200px;
}

body{margin: 0; font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.62;}
div{box-sizing: border-box;}

.Page{width: var(--PageWidth); margin: auto; background: Lime;}
.Page > .Navigation{position: fixed; width: var(--NavigationWidth); background: Cyan; padding: 15px;}
.Page > .Content{margin-left: var(--NavigationWidth); background: Pink; padding: 15px;}
```